# В Java коде --> из String с указанием года - двумя символами ==> в LocalDate()

Tags: java, строки, localdate

Необходимо парсить дату, которая приходит в виде строчки, т.е. например:

```
String data = "15-JAN-85";
```

`Date` - устаревший класс, но он понимает какой век использовать, т.е.

```
Date dateD = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yy").parse("15-JAN-85");
System.out.println("dataD = " + dateD);
```

выдаст ==> dataD = Tue Jan 15 00:00:00 MSK 1985

а

```
Date dateD2 = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yy").parse("15-JAN-05");
System.out.println("dataD2 = " + dateD2);
```

==> dataD2 = Sat Jan 15 00:00:00 MSK 2005

`LocalDate` этого не понимает и

```
String strTime = "15-Jul-85";
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd-MMM-yy");
LocalDate localDate = LocalDate.parse(strTime, formatter);
System.out.println(localDate);
```

==> 2085-07-15

я могу конечно парсить строчку и если последние две цифры > 22 менять на 19..    а если меньше, то ничего не менять
но тогда это перестанет работать в 2023 году
можно конечно и получать `LocalDate.now()` и сравнивать последние две цифры у этой даты и приходящие...

а есть может быть путь работать с LocalDate и указанием года - двумя цифрами без подобных сложностей?

Comment: "Date - устаревший класс, но он понимает какой век использовать" - ничего он не понимает... Вот какой у Вас год: 85, 1985, 2085, 85 до н.э.?! Либо вариант предложенный Nowhere Man, либо можно установить значение по умолчанию так: `new DateTimeFormatterBuilder().parseDefaulting(ChronoField.YEAR, Year.now().getValue())`.

Comment: Да, спасибо, у Nowhere Man отличный ответ, он мне помог, но к сожалению, я даже не могу проголосовать за этот ответ, так как у меня репутация еще меньше 15 (

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как показано в [ответе на английском SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29496149/13279831), cледует воспользоваться классом [`DateTimeFormatterBuilder`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatterBuilder.html) и его методами для обработки дат, чтобы создать требуемый экземпляр `DateTimeFormatter`:

- [`appendValueReduced`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatterBuilder.html#appendValueReduced-java.time.temporal.TemporalField-int-int-int-) для установки базового смещения
- [`parseCaseInsensitive`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatterBuilder.html#parseCaseInsensitive--) для обработки даты независимо от регистра (формат "MMM" обрабатывает названия месяцев в виде "Jan", "Feb")

```java
    public static LocalDate from(String s, int base) {
        System.out.print(s + " with " + base + " -> ");
        return LocalDate.parse(s, new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
            .parseCaseInsensitive()
            .appendPattern("dd-MMM-")
            .appendValueReduced(ChronoField.YEAR, 2, 2, base)
            .toFormatter()
        );
    }

String s = "15-JAN-1985";
System.out.println(from(s, 1900));
System.out.println(from(s, 1985));
System.out.println(from(s, 1990));
System.out.println(from(s, 2000));
```

Результаты:

```
15-JAN-85 with 1900 -> 1985-01-15
15-JAN-85 with 1985 -> 1985-01-15
15-JAN-85 with 1990 -> 2085-01-15
15-JAN-85 with 2000 -> 2085-01-15
```